# Backbone view rendering multiple models

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm playing with Backbone and am getting one model rendered 4 extra times in my list view.

I create and fetch the collection before calling history.start but I don't think that has to do with it.

I'm calling against an api that is only returning 2 models in json. The first model rendered shows up just once and the next shows 5 times in a row. This happens every time.

Here's my code.

https://gist.github.com/3843944

Comment: Can you post the code for the ServiceProviderView template?

Comment: I appended 2 templates to the end of the gist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 66 you have this line:

```
@$("div").append(view.render().el)
```

That gets called each time you render a service provider. Due to the generic selector, `div`, I think it's selecting every `div` that exists in the element. When you add the first entry, the only `div` that exists is `<div class='providers'>`. However, when it's rendering the second entry it's selecting that `div` and all new `div`'s created by the first service provider and appended to the template.

Try something like this:

```
@$el.append(view.render().el)
```

Comment: Fixed! Thanks. I had my head in the js too long.